# Trying to extract a string value between dots from a string column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

im trying to extract a default string value from a string column but without sucess.

This is the column with some string values:

```
      Unnamed: 0
57    PA.SQNTURBO.Bb20.0-Serquinutri Turbo - Bb20 L
58    PA.SQNTURBO.Fr 1l.0-Serquinutri Turbo - Frasco 1l
59    PA.SQNZ10.Bb 20.0-Serquinutri Zinco 10 - Bb 20 L
60    PA.sqnbor.Bb 20.0-Serquinutri Serquibor - Bb 20 L
61    PA.sqnbor.Bb 5.0-Serquinutri Serquibor - Bb 5l
```

What im trying to reach:

```
      Unnamed: 0
57    SQNTURBO.Bb20
58    SQNTURBO.Fr 1l
59    SQNZ10.Bb 20
60    sqnbor.Bb 20
61    sqnbor.Bb 5
```

this is my unsucess code:

```py
all_months["Unnamed: 0"] = all_months["Unnamed: 0"].str.extract(r"/.(.*)./", expand=False)
all_months
```

and the result...

```
      Unnamed: 0
57    NaN
58    NaN
59    NaN
60    NaN
61    NaN
```

Could you guys help me? i have a kinda difficult with regex and it just blow my mind when i have to deal with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get no matches as there are no slashes in your strings.

You can use

```
all_months["Unnamed: 0"].str.extract(r"\.([^.]*\.[^.]*)", expand=False)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KKn3LA/1). `Series.str.extract` will extract the first occurrence of the regex match. *Details*:

- `\.` - a `.` char
- `([^.]*\.[^.]*)` - Group 1 (the value returned by the `Series.str.extract`): zero or more non-`.` chars, a `.` char, and then zero or more chars other than `.`.

Pandas test:

```py
import pandas as pd
all_months = pd.DataFrame({'Unnamed: 0':['PA.SQNTURBO.Bb20.0-Serquinutri Turbo - Bb20 L',
    'PA.SQNTURBO.Fr 1l.0-Serquinutri Turbo - Frasco 1l',
    'PA.SQNZ10.Bb 20.0-Serquinutri Zinco 10 - Bb 20 L',
    'PA.sqnbor.Bb 20.0-Serquinutri Serquibor - Bb 20 L',
    'PA.sqnbor.Bb 5.0-Serquinutri Serquibor - Bb 5l']})
# >>> all_months["Unnamed: 0"].str.extract(r"\.([^.]*\.[^.]*)", expand=False)
# 0     SQNTURBO.Bb20
# 1    SQNTURBO.Fr 1l
# 2      SQNZ10.Bb 20
# 3      sqnbor.Bb 20
# 4       sqnbor.Bb 5
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following Pandas code using [`.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html#:%7E:text=extract,-Series.str.&text=Extract%20capture%20groups%20in%20the,match%20of%20regular%20expression%20pat%20.) function.

```
all_months["Unnamed: 0"].str.extract(r"^(?:[^.]*\.)([^.]*\.[^.]*)", expand=False)
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/HZphCk/1)

***Explanation of code:*** Simple explanation would be, using `.str.extract` function of Pandas on `Unnamed: 0` column of all_months DataFrame. Using regex in its main program and creating only 1 capturing group to get only required output as per shown samples.

***Explanation of regex:***

```
^(?:[^.]*\.)   ##From starting creating a non-capturing group where matching everything;
               ##from starting till 1st occurrence of dot here.
([^.]*\.[^.]*) ##Creating 1st and only capturing group of this solution, where matching;
               ##everything till dot including dot, followed by everything else before next occurrence of dot.
```